# renaming files in windows...perhaps dos command prompt (For)

Tags: dos

This kind of question has been asked a few times before on here and I have tried to use the answers in previous posts for my problem but I'm still struggling.

I have in a directory with 100's of files along the lines of

```
ab00123456.stp
ab00123457.stp
ab00123458.stp
```

...and so on

I would like to rename all these by adding a pre and post text to the file name.

So the end result would be...
    CDE_AB00123456_A.stp
    CDE_AB00123457_A.stp
    CDE_AB00123458_A.stp
...and so on

(Note the upper and lowercase text change also......as if this wasn't difficult enough already!)

Any clues would be much appreciated.....along the lines of some DOS command perhaps....

Andy

Answer (score 1):

`for /?` is extremely helpful. In particular, it contains the following substitutions:

> `%~nI`        - expands %I to a file name only
>    `%~xI`        - expands %I to a file extension only

Thus, you create a `for` loop that iterates through your files with iteration variable `%I` and renames `%I` to `CDE_%~nI_A%~xI`.

Ready-to-use example:

```
for %i in (*) DO echo rename %i CDE_%~ni_A%~xi
```

Try this in a directory of your choice, fine-tune it and remove the `echo` once you are satisfied.

Note that translation to upper-case is [much harder](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_convertcase.php), but since Windows is not case sensitive anyway, I'd just double-check if this is *really* required.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a batch script to do this.  But if you don't know how to script there are 100's of free file renaming tools.

here is a list of some
http://listoffreeware.com/list-of-best-free-file-rename-software/